# Understand downvotes on my initially well-received questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, down-votes, voting

Good afternoon,

Since I started using this website I've always tried to make my question better to satisfy the generous members sharing their knowledge.

Usually, I don't ask big questions, but short ones about curious facts in mathematics, or to help me solving a specific problem, learn some shortcuts, etc.

Two of my latest questions received a downvote right after they have been upvoted, and I can't figure out why. Here they are:

[Similarities between the Bessel $J_0(x)$ function and $f(x) = A\frac{\sin(bx+\varphi)}{cx+\phi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4596954/1107523)

[What's the equivalent of the Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)$ for $(n+\frac{1}{2})!!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4599845/1107523)

The fact they have been upvoted a least once show that they aren't "bad question", but I would be glad to know how to make them even better, in order to avoid downvotes.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions ! Have a lovely day.

---

**EDIT**: The question about Bessel is now at $-3$ while the other one has the same number of upvotes than downvotes. Moreover, my Bessel question has a close vote. I guess it is the most problematic. I changed a mistake in it thanks to @Accelerator, maybe it was a significant reason of the downvotes.

---

Since my last mofication, I'm happy to see that Bessel got $3$ new upvotes. Thank you everybody, next time I will do more research on my own before asking that kind of questions :-)

Comment: It's impossible for anyone but the downvoter to know why they downvoted so you're unlikely to get a satisfactory answer to your question here.  However, since both of the questions you've linked have comments beneath them linking to answers readily searchable, and the downvote mouse-over text clearly states "This question does not show any research effort..." it's possible that the downvoter feels you did not attempt to search for an answer before posting your question(s).

Comment: Understood, thanks ! 
NB: What do you mean by "downvote mouse-over" ?

Comment: And in the case where you received a prior upvote, in and of itself, does not communicate it is a good question.  One up vote, like one down vote, is not sufficient data for believing the question "must have been good", nor necessarily bad.

Comment: If you use a mouse, position it over the downvote arrow without clicking (hovering).  The desktop site then pops up a small text rectangle with a description of what downvotes should signify.

Comment: In both questions, your questions are lacking in context, and, one of them consists primarily of images with very little input from you.

Comment: Please read: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C131.5359).

Comment: Just like what the comments say, the two posts you linked have comments linking to answers that could easily be searched, so perhaps that is the reason for the downvotes. My issue with your first post, however, is that you mention the function $A\frac{\sin(bx+\varphi)}{cx+\varphi}$, but your screenshot has "$A.\sin(x+b)/(x+b)$". I can't make much sense of that.

Comment: @Accelerator thanks for pointing out that mistake, I have changed the title of the graph just now